# How do you challenge the 5th gym leader again?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How do you challenge the 5th gym leader again?  He's not there, so I can't do so.

Comment: Challenge him again?  Why do you need to challenge him again?

Comment: I didn't win that time so I can get my 5 gym badge

Comment: if you lost he should still be there

Answer (score 3):

I understand the issue you might be having.  You just need to go back to the gym and go to the right answer and go to the next floor, Bonnie will be on the next floor with another question.